# Remove error when defining xml attributes for Google Maps API

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-studio

I have added a set of xml attributes to the map fragment (Google Maps API for Android) but Android Studio keeps giving me this error: *Unexpected namespace prefix "map" found for tag fragment.*

How do I solve this error properly (without adding an ignore tag)?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: is `fragment` tag your root element ? If so can you try wrap it in another `Layout` and move `xmlns:map` to the root `layout` ?

Comment: No, it it not my root element. But shouldn't it only be defined inside of the fragment as this is the only place I need it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this also. This error is very similar to yours. [Android Google Maps fragment in the xml. I get "Unexpected namespace prefix"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024430/android-google-maps-fragment-in-the-xml-i-get-unexpected-namespace-prefix)

Look at the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

it happens sometimes, all you need to do is

Clean project then Go in `File>Invalidate Caches / Restart` and you should be good to go :)